# WPF Listbox grows outside screen size (MVVM light)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I have a typical MVVM structure. A mainwindow consists of some labels and a viewmodel (bound as ContentControl). This viewmodel has a listbox where I add entries. As the list grows the height of my viewmodel grows as well and thus the height of the whole application. Unfortunately the size doesn't stop at the edge of the screen and just grows out of the screen. I tried all the different size-restrictions on the mainwindow, the viewmodel is stretched in both dimensions.
Furthermore, I tried to get a scrollbar for the listbox but didn't succeed (or it's just there but not enabled if I force it.)

How can I restrict the maximal size to be the resolution of the screen (fullscreen) and get a scrollbar for the listbox when the size is reached?

€: Okay, here should be the relevant part of my code. I tried a fixed size of 1024x768 but even that doesn't work.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SWS.MainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Width="1024"
    Height="768"
    MaxWidth="1024"
    MaxHeight="768">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel in question

```
<UserControl x:Class="SWS.Views.ProgramView"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Width="65" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.PrV_Number}" />
            <Label Width="75" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.PrV_Weight}" />
            <Label Width="55" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.PrV_Action}" />
            <Label Content=" " />
        </DockPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ParticleCollection}" 
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Width="53" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Weight, StringFormat=F4}" Width="65" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Action}" Width="52" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML. Otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: will it work if you put your ListBox inside the ScrollViewer?

Comment: No, it still keeps growing. The ListBox or the ProgramView somehow doesn't know the size of the outer Window I suppose

Comment: Oh just seeing @Dilshod 's 2nd comment. That is the answer (* or 1*) to fill available space than get actual total height required

Comment: @Viv sorry I just removed it because of correction. Changing RowDefinition Height="auto" to RowDefinition Height="*1" might solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the row height to *  on your `Window` for `ContentControl` and your `ListBox` in `UserControl` to fill available space than try to get what it needs.

This worked fine:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SWS.MainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Width="1024"
    Height="768"
    MaxWidth="1024"
    MaxHeight="768">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SWS.Views.ProgramView"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Could also do this in a couple more ways:

In your `Window` you can just remove the `<Grid.RowDefinitions>...<Grid.RowDefinitions>` completely. The default behavior is what your looking for.

When you have more than 1 row you can either choose to specify `Height="*"` or just remove the `Height` Property from the `RowDefinition`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpfull